# Planar graphs and homomorphism graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I'm working with graphs. I would like to please be verified with this one.

**Draw, if possible, a planar representation of each graph:**

[image]

I got the planar representation of the 2nd graph. This is what I got.

[image]

I think the third is not possible. Is that right?

---

Also, do you know how to **show that the two graphs are homeomorphic?** I understood how to show that graphs are isomorphic, but I'm not really getting homeomorphism. I know that graphs are said to be homeomorphic if both can be obtained from the same graph by subdivisions of edges. But how can I show that they are homeomorphic?

[image]

The vertices don't have labels.

Comment: You are really asking two different questions here. I think it would be better if those were in separate posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned by Damascuz, for you first question you can use the fact that any planar graph has at most $3n-6$ edges. This limits can be derived from [hand-shaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) and [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula).

You might also know [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) : It states that a finite graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ (the complete graph on five vertices) or of $K_{3,3}$ (complete bipartite graph on six vertices, three of which connect to each of the other three).

[image]

In your third example, the graph contains a $K_{3,3}$ by grouping the verticex as $\{A,B,F\}$ and $\{C,D,E\}$ for instance.

For your **second question**. I disagree with Damascuz. Your graph are homeomorphic. The fact that they have the same number of vertices is not sufficient to only check for isomorphism. For the left graph, add a vertex on the diagonal. For the right graph, add a vertex on the *handle*, the edges that stick out of the square : you will end up with the same graph. Therefore the two graphs are homeomorphic.

[image]

Comment: Yeah as I said in the comment below my answer I was wrong about the homeomorphism thing. I tried tackling both questions but was unfamiliar with how to proceed on the second one. Your answer is very clarifying, now I see how it's done thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Paul Hudford.

Sorry to bother you again, can you let me know if I get it in here?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3684573/proof-of-homeomorphic-graphs

Answer (score 0):

There is a criterion for determining whether a graph is planar or not depending on the size $m$ (number of edges) and the order $n$ (number of vertices).

If $G$ is planar, then $m\leq 3n-6$

In your third graph this is clearly not true since $m=13$ and $n=6$.

However, if you'd like a more "geometric" way to prove it, you could try something like this:

Ignore for a moment the edges $AC$ and $DF$. Consider the non-planar representation of both $K_4$'s (complete graphs with 4 vertices) that you have, that is $ABDE$ on one hand, and $BCEF$ on the other.

Try untangling them to see how they are glued by the edge $BE$. Up to this point, you still have a planar graph, and you can see that you can either connect $A$ to $C$ or $D$ to $F$, but not both.

Give it a go, and I'll provide an image/tool for you to see for yourself if you're still not convinced.

In regards to your second question:

Two graphs are homeomorphic if there is a graph isomorphism between some subdivision of each.  Since you have the same number of vertices in each case, I don't think you have to consider subdivisions at all and it suffices to prove they are not isomorphic.

Graph isomorphisms are edge-preserving bijections, and clearly this is not the case for those two graphs. Consider $v$ the only vertex with $deg(v)=1$, and suppose there is a bijection $\phi$ from one graph to the other. In graph 1, $v$ is adjacent to some $u$ with $deg(u)=2$. In graph 2 $\phi(v)$ must be adjacent to $\phi(u)$. However, $deg(\phi(u))=3$, which contradicts $\phi$ preserving edge relations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the knowledge sharing. I didn't know about that formula criteria to determine whether a graph is planar or not, that's so much better.

Yes that's the way I proved they weren't isomorphic. That's done already. I'm trying to prove now that they are homeomorphic. I'm sorry but I still don't get how to do that. :-/

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying. I think I may have been wrong saying it suffices to prove they are not isomorphic, I'm not very well versed in graph homomorphisms myself. However, thinking about it, if I had to find subdivisions such that there is an isomorphism between these, I would probably focus on adding vertices to the edges of the $u$ and $\phi(u)$ I mentioned, since that vertex seems to be the troublesome one. Maybe subdividing those edges solves helps you find the correspondence you're looking for.