# Proof of homeomorphic graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have to demonstrate that graphs are homeomorphic. I know that graphs are said to be homeomorphic if both can be obtained from the same graph by subdivisions of edges.

@Paul Hudford here told me that the proof that these graphs

[image]

are homeomorphic is this

[image]

I'm demonstrating now that these graphs are homeomorphic.

[image]

I would like to know if with these graphs I've demonstrated that they are homeomorphic to see if I understood to keep going with the other ones I have.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi, No it looks like you did not understand the first case. In the red graphs, we said that they are homeomorphic because the two graphs after adding a subdivision in each are isomorphic. In the second table, the two red graphs are the same. just flip one over and move around the vertex, they are exactly the same : A cycle of lenth 4 and one handle of length 2. The question is : can you achieve the same with the blue graphs ? If not, why not ?

Comment: When subdividing edges, the degree of the original vertices does not change.  In the first table of the blue graphs, the one on the right has a vertex of degree 3, the one on the left has no vertex of degree 3. Hence it is not possible to create a vertex of degree three starting from the blue graph on the left by successively applying subdivision to the edges of the graph. Since it is not possible to generate a degree 3 vertex starting from the left graph, you cannot create a graph isomorphic to the one on the right. Hence the two blue graphs on the first blue graph table are not homeomorphic.

Comment: The correct expression is homomorphic.

Comment: @WilliamElliot The OP was already confused. Please don't add to the confusion by posting misinformation with an air of authority. The question is about [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)) (not homomorphism) of graphs.

Comment: @PaulHudford I thought that pulling up the midpoint that is now in the second table in the blue graph in the left I get the one in the right. This is a bit confusing to me. :-/ So when I add vertices to make a subdivision of edges, do I have to add the same amount of vertice to each one? How many vertices can I add to each one? Is there a limit?

Comment: @user614287 ohhh so they are not homeomorphic then? :-O

Comment: @gi2302, the reason for the possibility that the two blue graphs shown in the first row of blue graphs table is that one of them,namely the graph shown on the right side of the table, has a degree three vertex and the other one, namely the graph shown on the left, doesn't.  By imagining performing subdivision of the edges of the graph, it is not clear that it is possible to create a degree three vertex if there was no degree three vertex before. This is because that the action of doing a subdivision is by putting a vertex on an edge. But if you just put a vertex on an edge, that vertex

Comment: that new vertex has degree 2 only. me is going to say that since the old vertices are left unchanged, and that adding a new vertex only makes vertex of degree $2$, subdividing graph with no degree $3$ vertex is not going to be creating a vertex of degree $3$.  Also, subdividing the blue degree three vertex graph on the right of the table containing the first rows of blue graphs, we are not going to remove that degree three vertex. And therefore,  no matter how you perform the the sequence of subdivisions on the two blue graphs, it is believed that you will not make them into isomorphic graphs.

Comment: An easier way (for me) to see why they are not homeomorphic is to say that when adding a subdivision you cannot create or destroy a cycle. the graph on the left a no cycle, the one on the right has several, therefore they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: however @gi2302 I do not understant your sentence "pulling up the midpoint that is now in the second table in the blue graph in the left I get the one in the right" When you do such a "pull up", the edges follow, you don't create new ones... you will never create the square from a simple edge

Comment: ok ok ok...I think I get it now. Thanks so much for the help. <3